# How to get product collection without special price and tier price?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, tierprice, special-price

I'm using Magento v2.4, i want to retrieve a product collection that does not have special price (special price is not active or null) and tier price, currently i load the product collection like this:

```
public function __construct( ,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory  
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;     
}

public function getPurePriceProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
    //need to filter out special price and tier price from product collection
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: add below condtion.
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price',array('null' => true)); 
 $collection->getSelect()->where("e.entity_id not in (select entity_id From catalog_product_entity_tier_price)");

Answer (score 2):

You can check for special price in `addAttributeToFilter`

```
  protected $productCollection;   
  public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
  )
 {
    $this->productCollection = $collectionFactory;     
    parent::__construct($context);
    ...
 }
 public function execute()
 {
 $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $specialpriceColl = $this->productCollection->create();        
    $specialpriceColl->addAttributeToSelect('special_from_date')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('special_to_date')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['neq' => ''])
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', [ 'lteq' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($now))])
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', [ 'gteq' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($now))])                   
                ;       
    $pcollection = $this->productCollection->create();
    $pcollection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price',array('null' => true));         
    $pcollection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
    $subquery = new \Zend_Db_Expr($specialpriceColl->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns('entity_id'));        


    $pcollection->getSelect()->where(" ((at_special_price.value IS NULL) OR  (e.entity_id not in ($subquery)) ) AND  (e.entity_id not in (select entity_id From catalog_product_entity_tier_price))");    
    foreach($pcollection as $coll)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_R($coll->getData());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, How about if there is a product that has inactive special price date ?

Comment: $collection->addAttributeToSelect('special_from_date',['lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]); 

and

        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date',['gteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);


use it.\

Comment: not working i think need to put the special price in or condition with the date

Comment: check updated answer, You will get product collection item which has special price null or not  valid for start and todate for  current date and also not in tier price applied.